# Jquery .addClass() not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass

I copy paste this code in the page Im editing, from the page where I copied it its working properly but in my page it does not. I already added the link rel= code because I thought missing that was the cause why the jquery is not working but it still not, the codes from the page where I copied it to my page is exactly the same, so I wonder why its not working in mine.

One more thing, when I inspect element, I saw the class nivo-caption eventhough I deleted it for testing purposes, the .addClass part is the only not working whether i delete it or not. thank you for helping me, dont know much about jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.nivoSlider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random',
        slices: 15,
        boxCols: 12,
        boxRows: 6,
        animSpeed: 500,
        pauseTime: 8000,
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        prevText: '<i class="icon-angle-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>',
        afterLoad: function(){
            $('#slider').find('.nivo-caption').addClass('slider-caption-bg');
        }
    });

});
```

this is my html

```
<div class="nivoSlider">
                    <img src="images/slider/boxed/2.jpg" alt="Slider 1" title="#nivocaption1" />
                    <img src="images/slider/boxed/3.jpg" alt="Slider 2" title="#nivocaption2" />
                </div>

                <div id="nivocaption1" class="nivo-html-caption">Ultra Responsive Design</div>
                <div id="nivocaption2" class="nivo-html-caption">Unlimited Color Options</div>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: `$('#slider').find('.nivo-caption').addClass('slider-caption-bg');` Double check if `#slider` has children  `.nivo-option`

Comment: @sunny Can you also please provide `#slider` where it should contain `.nivocaption` ?.

Comment: my problem is i just copied the code from (ex)page.html and i pasted it in (ex)mypage.html, those html pages uses same css so i wonder why its not working in mine.

and only the `.find('nivo-caption')` is working. the .addClass does not

Comment: @sunny What is (ex)? Anyway, I checked the plugin source and found out that it calls the `afterLoad` callback very wisely at the end of the script `settings.afterLoad.call(this);`. So, if there's any error in the console log (F12) You should put it here. And if there's no error at all, that means your element `#slider` or `.nivo-caption` might not be available. As a test, I suggest you to just put an `alert('test')` inside your `afterLoad` callback and let see whether it calls an alert or not.

Comment: @choz its example (example)(ex). theres no error. it just kind of not reading the this part `$('#slider').find('.nivo-caption').addClass('slider-caption-bg');` whereas on the other page its working properly, baffling because i just copy pasted it.

ok i'll try it. thanks

Comment: @sunny Look, copy, & paste my answer. If your'e actually curious as to how and why of things ,let me know.

Comment: There is no #slider ID in your html...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, copy and paste what I have done in this snippet.

**UPDATE**

Go here: http://plnkr.co/edit/a4ywRcQyrHAqV5yTibFQ?p=preview

On the left, there's some file's:

1. index.html
2. script.js
3. style.css
4. insert.html

Open insert.html follow the directions and good luck.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>33907731</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nivoslider/3.2/nivo-slider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    .fa {
      font-size: 48px;
      color: blue;
      height: 48px;
      width: 18px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nivoslider/3.2/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/000/Fff.png&text=FIRST" alt="Slider 1" title="#nivocaption1" />
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/fff/000.png&text=LAST" alt="Slider 2" title="#nivocaption2" />
  </div>

  <div id="nivocaption1" class="nivo-html-caption">Ultra Responsive Design</div>
  <div id="nivocaption2" class="nivo-html-caption">Unlimited Color Options</div>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('.nivoSlider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random',
        slices: 15,
        boxCols: 12,
        boxRows: 6,
        animSpeed: 500,
        pauseTime: 8000,
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
        afterLoad: function() {
          $('.nivoSlider').find('.nivo-html-caption').addClass('slider-caption-bg');
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the script src wipe out all the contents on the body of my page, as for the html code doesnt make any changes :'(

Comment: What exactly do you have? Word-Press? A CMS? S3? You can't expect miracles by cutting and pasting. I took everything you posted then made it work. There are many factors at play when coding. -_-

Comment: html5 template. sorry i really dont know much.

Comment: No worries, I'm going to complete the code so it stands alone. Then you use a **blank** text file, paste my code on it, then rename the `.txt` part to `.html`

Comment: .....Ok it's ready. No problem, the addClass was targeted wrong but there's 2 types of caption. `.nivo-html-caption` and `.nivo-caption` so if the results for` .addClass` is not what you wanted try the other class. When you insert this code into your page, I suggest you make a <div> ....</div> first then place my code between <div> *HERE* </div>

Comment: Oh yeah, if you insert the code, you'll have to strip the <head> off and then add the <script>...</script> before the </body> of the file you're adding to. If this helped, don't forget to click the green checkmark. ;)

Comment: The answer has been updated  and there's a link with extra help concerning your problem. Good luck.